# Oracle Java Installer getting stuck trying to install on Mac arm64

Tags: java, arm

I am trying to install Java from Oracle on my 2020 ARM processor Macbook using the M1 chip. I downloaded the JDK 21.0.2 ARM64 DMG Installer, opened it, which opened the Java installation window. When I click "Continue" on the 'Introduction' page, it just keeps loading/spinning forever.

I have not been able to find anything online specifically about this issue of the installer being stuck on the 'Introduction' page for my Macbook specs.

Comment: https://sdkman.io/

Comment: You can try an installer from any of the other JDK vendors: Adoptium of Eclipse Foundation, Azul Systems, BellSoft, IBM, Red Hat, SAP, Amazon, Microsoft, and more.